# Subversion and OAuth

Tags: svn, authentication, oauth

I've installed apache2 and subversion (version 1.6.11). It works.
I'm using in my svn site user=subversion and password=subversion for authentication saved in to htpasswd file.

I would like to use another kind of authetication, via OAuth instead of htpasswd file.
I'm new in OAuth and I don't want to use authentication via DB.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

No you can't use OAuth with Subversion.  Subversion clients would need speecific support for OAuth and they do not have such support at this time.  As far as I know no one is working on adding such support either.

To support OAuth in general I suspect a client would need to support full HTML rendering (like a browser) because in general how OAuth works is the server redirects the user to another service to enter the authentication details.  That would add a huge amount of complexity to Subversion.

Subversion supports Basic, Digest, and Kerberos/NTLM authentication at this time.  The supported storage backing those authentication protocols varies based on the server/protocol being used.